# How to drop a column in Polars if it is all null

Tags: python, dataframe, python-polars

This is what I'm doing currently, but I want to see if there is something more "polar"-isc. As in, I don't want to loop through it manually, it may cause lack of optimization.

```
# Sample DataFrame with some columns containing only null values
df = pl.DataFrame({
    "A": [1, 2, 3, 4],
    "B": [None, None, None, None],
    "C": [5, None, 7, 8],
    "D": [None, None, None, None]
})


df = df.with_columns(
        pl.col("B").is_null().alias("B_null")
        )

columns_to_drop = [col for col in df.columns if df[col].is_null().sum() == len(df[col])]

df = df.drop(columns_to_drop)
```

Comment: What about `df[:, df.select(pl.all().is_null().all().not_()).row(0)]`?